# how to bare initilize git on server over ssh?

Tags: git

I have server which host a repository that I cloned using:

```
git clone ssh://username@domain.tld://work/repo/project1.git
```

Now I want to create repository called "project2" so I tried:

```
git init --bare ssh://username@domain.tld://work/repo/project2.git
```

but I get :

> usage: git init [-q | --quiet] [--bare]
>   [--template=] [--shared[=]]
>   []

also tried to use ssh to connect:

```
 ssh username@domain.tld
```

but I get:

> fatal: Interactive git shell is not enabled. hint:
>   ~/git-shell-commands should exist and have read and execute access.
>   Connection to domain.tld closed.

how can I create the repository project2.git?

Comment: `git init` creates a new repository (locally to wherever that command is being run) - what is the intended relevance of `ssh://username@domain.tld` in that command?

Comment: Is there a project2.git in domain.tld remote, or do you want to create a new repository locally?

Comment: @GoodDeeds I want to create bare repository on the domain.tld called project2.git

Comment: you can't do that from with git operating on your own machine. Do you have direct ssh access to the server? is it your server?

Comment: @AD7six it is a server for a friend.. but I tried to use ssh i could not because I get fatal: Interactive git shell is not enabled. hint: ~/git-shell-commands should exist and have read and execute access. Connection to domain.tld closed when I try: ssh username@domain.tld

Comment: That's a 'no' :). if you only have access to the server as git (or,  for a user with `git shell`) you don't have relevant access to the server. the tldr is you want to run `ssh some.server... git init /repos/are/here/new-repo`

Comment: @AD7six I have ftp access can I create it locally then upload it through ftp?

Comment: try :). It should work if you have sufficient permissions